# How to write a dictionary to tab-separated file without using Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

How do I write the following dictionary to a tab-separated file with the keys as column headers?

Code so far:

```
import csv
test_dict = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}

with open("output_file.txt", 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = list(test_dict.keys()), delimiter = '\t')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(test_dict)
```

I keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

pertaining to the `writerows()` function.

I am trying not to use Pandas.

Comment: `.writerows` expects an iterable of dictionaries (in this case it's trying to iterate over your dict will yields the keys, and since those keys are stings and not `dict`s that why you get that error)... so either give it that or use the singular version... `.writerow(test_dict)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DictWriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) expects an iterable of dictionaries. You are giving it only one dictionary - so it is trying to unroll that.

You can get around it by wrapping the `test_dict` in a list

```
writer.writerows([test_dict])
```

Or use the [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method

Answer (score 1):

The function `writerows` expects an list of `dicts` and you are passing only a `dict`.

Modify the code as below:

```
import csv
test_dict = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}

with open("output_file.txt", 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = list(test_dict.keys()), delimiter = '\t')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows([test_dict]) #passing an list of dicts
```

You can use the function `writerow` instead of `writerows` to write a single row to a file.

```
import csv
test_dict = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}

with open("output_file.txt", 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = list(test_dict.keys()), delimiter = '\t')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(test_dict) #passing single row
```